# Focus doesn't work with hover for MUI styled component?

Tags: css, material-ui

Not sure why this doesn't work, but I can't seem to use focus and hover in the same MUI styled component for React. Here is a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-wave-t4v23h?file=/src/App.js) to illustrate what I mean. When I click on the Select element, the background and border don't change colors:

[image]

```
const SelectStyle = styled(Select)(({ theme }) => ({
  width: "175px",
  border: `1px solid #C4CDD5`,
  borderRadius: 3,
  fontSize: "1.2rem",
  "&:hover": {
    backgroundColor: "#DFE3E8",
    border: `1px solid #919EAB`
  },
  "&:focus": {
    backgroundColor: "#54D62C",
    border: `1px solid #AAF27F`
  },
  "& .MuiSelect-select": {
    paddingTop: 5,
    paddingBottom: 5,
    fontSize: "1.2rem",
    alignItems: "center",
    display: "inline-flex"
  }
}));
```

Not sure why this is or how to fix it?

Comment: Is something wrong with my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Override `.Mui-focused` class like this :

```
  "&.Mui-focused": {
        backgroundColor: "#54D62C",
        border: `1px solid #AAF27F`
     }
```

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/restless-river-1iq0sf) is working example.

Comment: Do you have any idea why `&:hover` works but `&:focus` does not?